# Android Store and Retrieve Data

Tags: java, android, file

How do I store and retrieve private application data for my app? I have an activity that runs depending on certain parameters entered by the user (file path, volume, etc.) and I want to be able to store what they input and then retrieve it every time they open the activity.

Should I user FileWrite or FileOutputStream/FileInputStream?

---

UPDATE:
Currently I have this as the code for saving the string.

```
final String audioPathFN = "Audio_Path";
final String audioPathC = String.valueOf(path);
FileOutputStream saveAudioPath;
try {
    saveAudioPath = openFileOutput(audioPathFN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    saveAudioPath.write(audioPathC.getBytes());
    saveAudioPath.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now how do I retrieve the string so I can use it in the app?

Comment: Here are your options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mechanisms to store private data :

- [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
- using a [simple file](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in you `activity.getCacheDir()` folder
- a [database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

All those options are explained here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Of course, all those solutions are local, you can also wanna use a web-service to communicate data with a server, but you would then be entering in a totally different landscape.